# lookup_events using boto3 is not returning event details

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, boto3

I am using code below but not getting back required event details. I verified that event id is correct and checked that details returned from aws UI

I have also tried without single quote before and after event id but that did not return details as well.

```
client = boto3.client('cloudtrail',region_name='us-east-1')
        response = client.lookup_events(
            LookupAttributes=[
                {
                    'AttributeKey': 'EventId',
                    'AttributeValue': "'" + str(eventid) + "'"
                },
            ],

            MaxResults=1,

        )
```

Below is response that i recieved , events is empty.

```
{u'Events': [], 'ResponseMetadata': {'RetryAttempts': 0, 'HTTPStatusCode': 200, 'RequestId': 'ea8888ab-0987-1234-4321-096c31sdfsdf', 'HTTPHeaders': {'x-amzn-requestid': '345551dd-1234-9876-1221-sddweerwer', 'date': 'Sat, 11 Nov 2017 17:08:20 GMT', 'content-length': '13', 'content-type': 'application/x-amz-json-1.1'}}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For attributes try

```
LookupAttributes=[
    {
        'AttributeKey': 'EventId',
        'AttributeValue': "{}".format(eventid)
    },
]
```

If not, perhaps triple check that `eventid` is defined?

Answer (score 0):

Don't put quotes around the EventId. You only need quotes when passing a raw value via Python -- the actual value should not have quotes.

```
'AttributeValue': eventid
```